# "Masquerade" mail sender on a multi-domain shared hosting

Tags: centos, postfix, virtualhost

I've a single host with CentOS 6.3. I manage that host via SSH. The server itself is `uname -n`: `servername.foo.com`. On this host I've multiple, **unrelated** httpd vhosts.

The problm is: when one vhost sends a mail with PHP mail(), the sent mail header contains multiple `servername.foo.com` traces (Message ID is xyx@servername.foo.com, Received by is servername.foo.com and so on).

The mail are sent by postfix. No other mail services are used on this server.

The question is: **how can I sent e-mail from each vhost pretending to be thatVhost.com** instead of leaving traces of servername.foo.com in the mail headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. [It has been asked](https://serverfault.com/q/90883/218590) long time ago and yet the answer is still no.

Parameter `myhostname` in **main.cf** was used to control the Message-ID/Received value in mail header. By default `myhostname` was set to hostname of server (`uname -a`). If you want to change `servername.foo.com` to another name then you can define that paramater. But again, you can't has `myhostname` unique per virtual host. SMTP isn't HTTP who has header `Host`.